# AWS Lambda | How use layer imported dependencies?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, python-module

So I am very new to AWS in general and I am trying to execute some code using Lambda.
Since my code has dependencies that need to be imported like the `request module` I have tried many ways to add the module.
After some research, I found out that there are 2 possible ways to do this. You can either include the zip file with the dependencies into the code source or import it into a Layer and then connect that layer to my function.

I chose the second for a few reasons. The problem now is that I can use the module requests inside the lambda_function.py file, but not the other files.

I know that I am missing something, but I do not know what I am missing.

My folder structure:

```
MyFirstFunction/
├── lambda_function.py
├── scripts/
│   ├── file0.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file2.py
│   └── file3.py
└── remote.py
│   
└── server.py
│   
└── executescript.py
```

**The Function Logs**

```
START RequestId: fa72c61d-2e34-4025-aa81-6205e8be288d Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "executescript.py", line 8, in <module>
from server import Server
File "/var/task/server.py", line 1, in <module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
END RequestId: fa72c61d-2e34-4025-aa81-6205e8be288d
REPORT RequestId: fa72c61d-2e34-4025-aa81-6205e8be288d  Duration: 753.01 ms Billed Duration: 754 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 50 MB  Init Duration: 228.97 ms
```

This line 8 from the error above is the following line:

```
from server import Server
```

And the first line of the server.py file is:

```
import requests
```

**How I tested that the module does get imported:**

I just wrote the line:

```
import requests
```

Inside the lambda_functions.py file and **including** the layer it gave no error and when I deleted the layer it gave the following error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'
```

Which shows me that the module is imported.

**My Question**

What do I need to change in order to let the server.py file use the requests module (and other modules)?

Comment: `requests` is your dependency and you don't have it in your lambda package. Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) to learn how to prepare a python lambda package. Or [create a layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

Comment: @baduker I have created a layer, imported the zip file with the request module and linked the function to the layer

Comment: Have you made sure that the dependencies are installed in the `python` folder?